# Convert superscript 2 (²) symbol to string

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, unicode-normalization

I am trying to get a string of code from some lisp files, to create unix filenames and display it on web pages:

```lisp
(let ((code "(defun ² (x) (* x x))"))
 (second (read-from-string code)))
```

Which evaluates to `|2|`. In fact, just typing `'²` evaluates to `|2|`, instead of `|²|`.

The `code` string is read from a file. I'm using SBCL 2.2.10.

With this scheme, the string `"x²"` is parsed the same as the string `"x2"` :

```lisp
(read-from-string "x²")
(read-from-string "x2")
```

How can I make `read-from-string` correct, without modification on the code in the string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See sect. 7.1.2 of [SBCL manual](https://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Symbol-Name-Normalization). By default, SBCL extends the reader to normalize all symbols. You can prevent this for current readtable by

`(setf (sb-ext:readtable-normalization *readtable*) nil)`